# how to generate bootstrap form in drupal with search_block_form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drupal, drupal-7

```
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-btn btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-filter dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">全部<span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">全部</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">模板</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">素材</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">教学</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">音频</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /btn-group -->
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-search" type="button">搜索</button>
                </span>
            </div><!-- /input-group -->
        </div>
```

Here is my html code ,writed based on Bootstrap 3,

and now ,I want to use this to Drupal,but Drupal generate some html,It's useless for me ,Somebody can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the template.
The template is named 'search-block-form.tpl.php'.
put a file called 'search-block-form.tpl.php' in your theme directory and add whatever html you want.
[template file docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search-block-form.tpl.php/7)

I think the template already gets the rendered html form though, so you may want to use a preprocess function too.
This function should be called `MYTHEMENAME_preprocess_search_block_form(&$variables)` and it should reside in your themes template.php file.
[preprocess function docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.module/function/template_preprocess_search_block_form/7)